# Rails Users updating information in custom routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

Not sure how to title my question...

My intent is that users will have a list of items (and only the current_user can edit this list)

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items
end
```

I have a Users controller (note: I'm also using devise gem, but created a separate Users Controller)

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def list
    @user.items.build
  end

  private
    def set_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(
        items_attributes: [:user_id, :item, :name, :_destroy]).merge(user_id: current_user.id)
    end
end
```

Right now I have set up routing

```
get 'users/:id/list', to: 'users#list', as: :list
```

Which gives me this: `localhost:3000/users/1/list`

Theoretically, this should be the show view... where it'll populate the list of items for user id: 1.

I want to be able to do `localhost:3000/list/edit` So the user can update this list.

My form in **views/users/list.html.erb** (I'm using cocoon gem for help with nested forms).

```
<%= simple_form_for @user do |f| %>

  <%= f.simple_fields_for :items do |i| %>
    <%= f.text_field :item %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  <% end%>

  <%= link_to_add_association 'add item', f, :items %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>

<% end %>
```

I know my form is in my list.html.erb where it'll populate all the items, but I'm just doing this for testing purposes.

How do I update the form to save into items database and its associated with the current user?

EDIT:

```
def update
  @user = current_user.items.find_by_user_id(current_user.id)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @user.update(user_params)


      format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'Congrats on your successful update!' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @user }
    else
      format.html { render :edit }
      format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with having a form in a "show" view. If you only want the `current_user` to view the form, then wrap your form in an if statement:

```
<% if @user == current_user %>
  (form goes here...)
<% end %>
```

As long as you have an `update` route/action for `users`, that form should submit (disclaimer: I've never used the `cocoon` gem).

Edit: Your form should be fine as is. Add this route to your `routes.rb` file:

```
patch 'users/:id', to: 'users#update'
```

Comment: Well, I'm trying to figure out what my update action and route would be for the form and when (or if) it needs to be edited, what that action would look like

Comment: Added the route to my answer

Comment: Now I get `The action 'update' could not be found for UsersController`. Do I just copy from another update action that I've scaffolded?

Comment: Oh, yeah, the `update` action is just a regular update method. So yeah you can copy it. Just make sure to replace any variables so they make sense.

Comment: So close!! I'm getting `unknown attribute 'items_attributes' for Item.` Any ideas? This should be from my params right? But I believe all my attributes are correct

Comment: No. It should be `@user = current_user`. Calling `.items` retrieves all the items belonging to the `user`.

Comment: But thats what I wanted. Right? Where the user can only update their own items

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84750/discussion-between-hellomello-and-ryan-k).

Comment: Yes, but you have a nested form. Which means that (if you have it setup right) when you update the `user`, all of the associated `items` will update too. Of course, you'll need to have `accepts_nested_attributes_for` defined in your `user` model (more on that [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods/accepts_nested_attributes_for)). But this is the correct way of doing it. I would read up on nested resources first.

Comment: Not sure, but when I removed the `.merge` in the params, it worked. I changed it to `@user = current_user`, but I have another issue... but I'll put that for another question, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For current user authentication you should use `cancan` gem
https://github.com/ryanb/cancan

For nested fields related to user `nested_form` gem is the best option
https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form

Comment: This didn't really help me. @RyanK's answer helped me!

Comment: Sure. I have used these two gems in my projects and  they just made my life easy.